# Use dynamic text size .largeTitle but always 18% larger than normal in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, fonts

I want to use dynamic text sizes in the system font.  But our design wants the default large title to be a bit bigger than the 34pt Apple default.

How do I make my SwiftUI style
`.font(.largeTitle)`
relatively larger, i.e. 40pt at system default text size, but still scale proportionately when the user changes the system text size?  Always 18% bigger than a normal .largeTitle.

I don't want to specify the San Francisco font name using
`.custom(<name>, size: <Float>, relativeTo: <Font.TextStyle>)`
as this generates a warning and misses out on getting the best optical variant.

I can use UIFont functions to adjust font metrics but I cannot convert the too-small SwiftUI Font to UIFont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this extension to UIFont to get the dynamic font size for a given TextStyle…

```
public extension UIFont {
    static func textStyleSize(_ style: UIFont.TextStyle) -> CGFloat {
        UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: style).pointSize
    }
}
```

Then my SwiftUI ViewModifier can use and scale that.  e.g:

```
.font(.system(size: UIFont.textStyleSize(.largeTitle) * 1.176, weight: .bold))
```

This gets the correct optical variant (such as the Display version for large, or more readable variant for small sizes) for the exact size I want as well as scaling relatively with the user's selected text size. Picking the text style closest to the desired size to base my size on helps to get the best proportions.

This seems the best available approach to me.

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all — I copied your code exactly and added the extension, but the resulting text doesn't scale at all. It stays at the `*1.176` scale, regardless of scaling preference.

Comment: Make sure you don't have another font modifier (for example `.font(.largeTitle)`) as that messes up the new modifier

Comment: This does not work as intended. I've tried it with a clean slate, it does not scale. Bruce, I could post a working solution that does not use UIFont at all if you'd like?

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer here by Ashley Mills](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75397114/16370901).

In case it gets removed I'll repeat it here:

```swift
extension Font {
    static let fortypt = Font.custom("", size: 40, relativeTo: .title)
}
```

To change the font, add the name (eg. for rounded system font, this works on iOS 15, I think you can just do `.fontDesign(.rounded)` on iOS 16.1+):

```swift
extension Font {
    static let fortypt = Font.custom(".AppleSystemUIFontRounded-Regular", size: 40, relativeTo: .title)
}
```

Then you can use the type like any other:

```swift
Text("Dynamic 40pt text")
    .font(.fortypt)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to achieve this without resorting to UIFont.
But the Font.custom("" …approach did not give me San Francisco system font, so I reverted to my method above.

Comment: Ah, okay. There's another part of the answer I linked to which shows how to get the exact font name you are using, which you could then use within the `""`. Out of interest, what are the downsides to using UIFont here?

Comment: UIFont works fine though I would prefer the newer Font class to the old UI one if possible.  

As I said in the Q, specifying a San Francisco font name generates a warning, and I want the OS to pick the best variant of San Francisco font for the style size.  My solution does that and I haven't seen any better ways.

I have a custom font modifier that takes a simple point size and weight.  It finds the nearest system dynamic size to that point size on a list of the *default* sizes, and then scales the dynamic size.  So if I asked for 30pt, it'd use dynamic .Title with size * 1.07.