# iOS Dynamic Type sizes — possible to change default sizes / have pt sizes in between styles?

Tags: css, swift, swiftui

[See here for Apple's Dynamic Type sizes](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/foundations/typography/#platform-considerations).

I want to use dynamic font sizing, to make text in my app scale according to accessibility settings. However, the default pt sizes don't cover what I require.

Eg.:

> Title 1 — 28pt

> Title 2 — 22pt

I want to be able to use a 24pt font, with dynamic sizing. With the Large (default) setting, this is not possible... but if the user has the xLarge setting, `Title 2` actually scales to 24pt...

As I am targeting iOS 15, I am using these modifiers on my `Text` so I can use a rounded font with dynamic sizing:

```swift
.font(.system(.title2, design: .rounded))
.fontWeight(.regular)
```

I've searched and searched, but [none](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72311863/16370901) of the [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72307778/16370901) answers work for me. I like the idea of being able to scale the existing dynamic type sizes by a multiplier but if I use `.scaleEffect(value)` it created pixellation when scaling up, and messes with padding even when scaling down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a font with a custom point size that scales with other dynamic fonts using:

```
Font.custom(_:size:relativeTo:)
```

e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Title").font(.title).border(.green)
            Text("Title").font(.title1½).border(.blue)
            Text("Title").font(.title2).border(.red)
                
        }
    }
}

extension Font {
    static let title1½ = Font.custom("", size: 24, relativeTo: .title2)
}
```

(leaving the `name` blank seems to return the system font)

[image]

You can adapt this to use rounded fonts in iOS 15. First you'll need to find the name of the font itself, using UIKit:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .regular)
let fontDescriptor = font.fontDescriptor.withDesign(.rounded)!
let roundedFont = UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptor, size: 24)
print(roundedFont.fontName)

// .AppleSystemUIFontRounded-Regular
```

You can use this in your custom Font method:

```
extension Font {
    static let title1Rounded = Font.custom(".AppleSystemUIFontRounded-Regular", size: 28, relativeTo: .title)
    static let title1½Rounded = Font.custom(".AppleSystemUIFontRounded-Regular", size: 24, relativeTo: .title2)
    static let title2Rounded = Font.custom(".AppleSystemUIFontRounded-Regular", size: 22, relativeTo: .title2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems great and works well. Only one thing — how can I set the font design to `rounded`? As I'm targeting iOS 15 I can't use `.fontDesign(.rounded)`, and I can't find a way to add it as a parameter with `.custom(...`

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Do write an answer here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72299093/use-dynamic-text-size-largetitle-but-always-18-larger-than-normal-in-swiftui/72307778#72307778